# Cksum for files in Clear Case

Tags: file, clearcase, versions

Will it be possible to find the cksum for all versions of a file in Clear Case?

Eg: Lets assume a code "X" has got 4 versions on the main branch. Will it be possible to find the cksum of all the 4 versions of file "X" at a time?
Is there any command available to find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no checksum or SHA1 associated with each version in ClearCase (like there would be in Git commit or SVN revision).

There is an **`oid`**, [from which you can identify an element](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21234502) (file or folder).

From a file, you can grep for this oid. In Windows, that would give:

```
cleartool dump foo.c@@ | findstr oid
```